# Calculating Quiecent Collector current in an inductor coupled transistor

Tags: transistors, dc, power-electronics

I have a class A power amplifier like the following circuit. I need to analyze the circuit to calculate \$I_c\$ proper values for \$R1, R2\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvLMnK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is a solution to the Ic current like,
$$I_c = \frac{V_3}{R_4}$$

By drawing the equivalent DC analysis circuit, we're omitting the R4, but how can we include it in the Ic expression? Any hints?

----------- The answer I'm referring to -----------
[image]

Comment: Duplicate question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264039/bjt-amplifier-negative-feedback-question/264088?s=1|0.2258#264088  except Rc changes to 2pi*f*L and caps are assumed large enough and Vin very small but still badly distorted output since Vin is operating in the nonlinear modulation of Vbe rather than modulating a small linear V(Re)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, assuming by \$I_C\$ you mean the DC bias current into the collector. In this circuit, \$I_C\$ is determined mainly by R3 and the voltage bias point produced by R1 and R2.

Comment: Hello @The Photon I've updated my question with the answer i'm referring to. The answers are given and if I do like how you suggested (also I feel correct), they're not the answers in the tute. I was wondering if there's any other type of an analysis to simplifiy a circuit like this.

Answer (score 0):

An approximation of Ic for the schematic shown would be:

Ic = ( (V3/2) - Q1(VBE) ) / R3

But this would only apply where V3/2 is greater than Q1 VBE.

The first problem with the schematic you have is of course that you specify V3 as 1 V. The minimum VBE of the 2n3904 is about 0.65 V.

Therefore the voltage on Q1 base would not allow it to conduct at all with a 1 V V3 supply. You'd need at least 1.2 V to get any conduction, and the Ic values would in uA.

If V3 was 3 V, then you'd get an Ic of about 8.5 mA.

The second problem is that you show an AC input signal at 1 kHz and the 1 uH  collector impedance is way too low to provide any AC gain for audio frequencies.